# Why does my stored procedure not recognize my varchar string?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I currently have a stored procedure in MySQL called `Admin_Emails`, which accepts three parameters: `siteID VARCHAR(20)` `categoryID INT` `approved INT`

The `siteID` is always in the following format: `s-xxx(x)-xxxxxx`.

In the procedure I add the `siteID` to my query using the following:

```
IF(siteID IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
        SET @query = CONCAT(@query, " AND e.site_id = ", siteID);
END IF;
```

If I run the procedure (ex. `CALL Admin_Emails('s-osp-123ABC', 2, 1)` then I get the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 's' in 'where clause'
```

The `s` is coming from the `siteID` string. I tried modifying my `CONCAT` statement to the following:

```
SET @query = CONCAT(@query, " AND e.site_id = ", "'" + siteID + "'");
```

which will not produce an error, but will give me results with `siteID's` that do not match the input. I purposely produced an error by excluding the `AND` in the query, and it was showing a `0` where the `siteID` should be:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'e.site_id = 0 AND e.category_id = 2 AND e.is_approved != 0' at line 20
```

I'm at a loss. I've tried searches for issues related to `VARCHAR` strings in stored procedures, but can't find similar situations. Is anyone aware of what I'm doing wrong here?

I didn't want to overload with the whole procedure, so I'm hoping that what I've provided here is enough, but if not I can produce more of my procedure.

Comment: why not `CONCAT(@query, " AND e.site_id = ", "'", siteID,"'");` are the +'s trying to do math with the siteID value?  I'd recommend printing out the SQL before it executes so you can visually see where the problem lies in the SQL.... does the query end in an `or` not encased in ()'s which would cause the simple addition of an and to not produce the desired results?

Comment: What type is _siteID_? Also, show the whole query string that produces the error 1064

Comment: @xQbert I feel stupid now. That worked perfect. If you make it an answer I will accept it from you. Thank you!

Comment: @SloanThrasher `siteID` is a varchar string. And the reason the 1064 error is being produced is because the query basically says `WHERE e.date < NOW() e.siteID = 0 AND ...` It skips the `AND` between the date and siteID columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not

```
CONCAT(@query, " AND e.site_id = ", "'", siteID,"'");
```

Seems odd to try and `+` when concat() supports n values of string concat...

I think ++ is trying to do math which is resulting in the error.

Or you have an `or` limit at the end of the query and with the addition of and.... if the or doesn't have proper ()'s it could cause the issue of unexpected results.

Be warned if SiteID passed in isn't properly sanitized, you have SQL injection possibilities now.

Comment: Thank you again. Worked perfect! You're correct that it seemed to be trying to do some addition. Not really sure what made me think to use the + method.

Comment: Well framed question.  enough detail to figure out what was going on.  Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes.

Comment: Would you recommend a better way of including the site ID in my query? I am using PDO for my queries. I prep the query, then pass the variables through the execute statement. The site ID itself is pulled from the database, and not allowed to be entered by a user. Not to say someone couldn't hack the database and change the site ID's, though.

Comment: Not really. Sounds like you're doing what you can and it's being properly sanatized.  The fact that siteID comes from the database and isn't allowed to be entered by a user cleared up my concern (especially if it's sanitized/formatted) before save can occur.  If someone hacks the db/ you have bigger issues then injection.